# Xamarin Forms CollectionView not working correctly (support libraries?)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm at my wits end. I'm trying to implement a xamarin.forms collectionview control. However, the component behaves strangely, specifically in Android. It started out with some padding being added to the collectionview left and right side. At first, I thought it was a bug in the collectionview component. However, when I tried to reproduce the issue using a test project, I couldn't. After spending half a day comparing the projects, I discovered that in our app, we were using all kinds of android support libraries, and the test project only used the Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils library. After removing the other support libraries, the component started behaving better and the padding was gone.

So I thought I fixed it!

However, it turns out the collectionview behavior of the testing project is still different. Specifically with background colors. I render a ContentView inside the DataTemplate of the CollectionView, and it defines some elements with background color. The background color of an outer element doesn't seem to propagate to underlying elements.

After moving the entire contents of the content view to the datatemplate of the collectionview itself, everything worked fine.

Does anyone know what might be going on?
I know this a vague question, but I hope someone recognizes some behavior from my description and can give me a clue on what's happening.

Comment: That's a nice story however If you can attach some images that would be more helpful.

Comment: You could provide the code with errors. It would be helpful for us  to test.